Glance Widget size not correct
I have simple widget, that I want to have 110x40dp. Here is my definition:
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/glance_default_loading_layout"
    android:minWidth="110dp"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:minResizeWidth="110dp"
    android:minResizeHeight="40dp"
    android:resizeMode="none"
    />

Here is my provideContent block of code in widget:
provideContent {
    Box(modifier = GlanceModifier.size(110.dp, 40.dp).background(color = Color.Green.copy(alpha = 0.5f))) 
        Text(text = "ThemeId from prefs = $themeId")
    }
}

The problem is, that the green area, that I want to create as a base area for my layout, is just not the correct size. It is a lot smaller. It seems that 110x40 defined in appwidget-provider is not the same as the one devined in provideContent block. Can somebody tell me how to do this, or what is the recommended way of defining widgets? I see that there is just lack of documentation, regarding creation of nice widgets. Thank you.

"that I want to have 110x40dp" -- how do your intentions map to the documentation on app widget sizing, especially the use of minWidth and minHeight for sizing?
